# How to test whether I need to cluster standard errors?

Tags: panel-data, clustered-standard-errors

I am working with panel data (flights per month of several airlines). I suppose that I need to cluster standard errors since OLS errors are not valid. Is there a way to test whether I indeed need to cluster errors and how to check across which dimension the clustering is required (e.g. airlines/type of aircraft/destinations etc)? Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: It looks like you’re after the Hausman test for fixed or random effects.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Wu%E2%80%93Hausman_test?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @GuilhermeMarthe thanks for your reply! However, as far as I understand, the Hausman test could indicate whether the fixed effect model is preferred over the random effect model. But this does not directly relate to clustering?

Comment: It depends. What is the goal of your research?

Comment: @ThomasBilach thanks for your response. I am studying flight delay propagation, in particular, which factors affect whether a delay is going to propagate. So as a dependent variable I have propagated delays for 10 airlines, and some airline/airport-specific characteristics as explanatory variables. To see which factors are actually significant I want to make sure that the standard errors are valid, thus I want to make sure that clustering is needed and to possibly check across which dimension.

Comment: I assume delays in the early part of the day have some downstream effects. Maybe some airlines don't include enough of a buffer period in between flights. Are you observing propagated delays over many time periods? Do you suspect any "within-airline" correlation in propagated delays over time?

Comment: @ThomasBilach My dataset includes propagated delays of all flights performed within one month by 10 airlines. Yes, based on theoretical arguments I assume that there might be a ''within-airline'' correlation. But also, it might be that there is a correlation between airline and time of the day or destination. So, my concern is whether to cluster errors by airlines, or maybe perform a two-way clustering by airlines and time of the day or any other dimension. Is there a way to ''evaluate'' what kind of clustering is preferred?

Comment: Clustering on both dimensions is permissible. How many time periods do you have?

Comment: @ThomasBilach the panel is unbalanced, so the number of time periods depends on the airline. Generally, I have 1500-3000 observations per airline.

Comment: By observations do you mean flights or time periods? I assume you're observing data for each of the 10 airlines over time.

Comment: @ThomasBilach I mean flights but I assume one flight to be ''equivalent''  to the time period.

Comment: I only assumed this because of the 'panel data' tag. So you sampled all flights within given month at *separate* airlines? Is this a more accurate description of your data?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Yes, so I'm not sure how to correctly specify the number of time periods.

Comment: In my understanding, random effects are just a different nomenclature for multilevel/clustered/grouped/hierarchical observations. https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2005/01/25/why_i_dont_use/

With that in mind, I think the Hausman test could be what you are after.